# Query SUM for two fields in two different tables

Tags: mysql, sum

I am trying to determine how to do sum fields between two tables.

In table 1, we'll call it gegevens for short, I would have, for example, gegevenID, vertrekdatum, prijs

In table 2, we'll call it fees, I would have , for example, feeID, gegevenID, amount

I want to take and sum the values for prijs based on year(vertrekdatum) from gegevens.

I had tried to do a LEFT JOIN and it worked until there were two records for the same gegevenID in the fee's table., then it doubled the prijs.

Table example:

```
GEGEVENS
----------------------------------
gegevenID | vertrekdatum | prijs |
----------------------------------
|      1  | 2011-01-01   |1385.88|
|      2  | 2011-03-01   | 450.26|
|      3  | 2012-01-01   |2505.10|
----------------------------------

FEES
----------------------------
feeID | gegevenID | amount |
----------------------------
|   1 |         2 |   50.00|
|   2 |         2 |  126.00|
|   3 |         3 |   50.00|
----------------------------
```

The results that I *want* are

```
TOTALS
--------------------------------------------
| year | SumOfPrijs | SumOfFees |  Total   |
--------------------------------------------
| 2011 |  1836.14   |   176.00  |  2012.14 |
| 2012 |  2505.10   |    50.00  |  2555.10 |
--------------------------------------------
```

This query resulted in the doubled 'prijs' when it took into account there were two rows in the fees table for one gegevenID.

```
SELECT sum(prijs) as SumOfPrijs, sum(amount) as SumOfFees, sum(prijs)+sum(amount) AS   
Total, year(vertrekdatum) as year
FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg
LEFT JOIN tbl_fees f
ON f.gegevenID = vg.gegevenID

WHERE vertrekdatum <=NOW()
GROUP by year(vertrekdatum)
```

Any thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use a subquery to aggregate the fees table before the join:

```
SELECT sum(prijs) as SumOfPrijs, sum(amount) as SumOfFees, sum(prijs)+sum(amount) AS   
Total, year(vertrekdatum) as year
FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg LEFT JOIN
     (select f.gegevenId, sum(amount) as Amount
      from tbl_fees f
      group by f.gegevenId
     ) f
     ON f.gegevenID = vg.gegevenID
WHERE vertrekdatum <=NOW()
GROUP by year(vertrekdatum);
```

The problem is that the multiple fees on on "gegeven" is causing the join to produce unexpected rows, that affect the sum.

Comment: this is perfect. thanks so much for the help. 

I had tried a similar option, but it would not yield any results if there were no values in the fee table that matched the gegevenID in the tbl_vluchtgegevens table.

Answer (score 4):

Joining in any form will double the values when there are two `gegevenID` rows in `fees` (or triple them if there are three, and so on).

The best workaround I can think of is to calculate the sums independently - one subquery for  price and one subquery for fees - and then put the results together:

```
SELECT
  p.year,
  p.SumOfPrijs,
  f.SumOfFees,
  p.SumOfPrijs + f.SumOfFees AS Total
FROM (
  SELECT
    YEAR(vertrekdatum) AS year,
    SUM(prijs) AS SumOfPrijs
  FROM gegevens
  GROUP BY YEAR(vertrekdatum)
) p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    YEAR(vertrekdatum) as year,
    SUM(amount) AS SumOfFees
  FROM gegevens
  INNER JOIN fees ON gegevens.gegevenID = fees.gegevenID
  GROUP BY YEAR(vertrekdatum)
) f ON p.year = f.year
```

There's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ed33/1).

Comment: Hi Ed. thanks for your help on this. This query also did exactly what I was hoping for. I have a lot to learn...