# Sum the column of the table

Tags: mysql, sum

I have 2 tables below:

```
Table1
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| date      | TRAFFIC1   | PAYLOAD11 | PAYLOAD12 |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|2015-01-01 | 2          | 2         | 2         |
|2015-01-01 | 3          | 3         | 3         |
|2015-01-02 | 2          | 2         | 2         |
|2015-01-02 | 3          | 3         | 3         |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+

Table2
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| date      | TRAFFIC21  | PAYLOAD21 | PAYLOAD22 |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|2015-01-01 | 2          | 2         | 2         |
|2015-01-01 | 3          | 3         | 3         |
|2015-01-02 | 2          | 2         | 2         |
|2015-01-02 | 3          | 3         | 3         |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to sum payload from 2 tables above group by date?

Comment: Put your tables structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date, SUM(payload) FROM (
SELECT date, `PAYLOAD11` + `PAYLOAD12` as payload FROM Table1
union all
SELECT date, `PAYLOAD21` + `PAYLOAD22` as payload FROM Table2) grp
GROUP BY date
```

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a4453/3)**

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.payload)+SUM(t2.payload) AS total FROM table1 AS t1,table2 AS t2 GROUP BY date
```

for more check this: [Query SUM for two fields in two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148188/query-sum-for-two-fields-in-two-different-tables)

Comment: But you have to join some fields between your tables